# Swift nested dictionary returns always optionals

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

Im trying to send a nested dictionary to an API. Even though none of the properties inside `address` is declared as optional, when I print this dictionary everything inside `address` is optional and the rest is non-optional. How to avoid this? Will creating a model and encoding that model to a dictionary result in the same behaviour?

```
    var data = [
        "individual": [
            "address": [
                "city": placemark.locality,
                "country": placemark.isoCountryCode,
                "line1": line1,
                "line2": line2,
                "postal_code": placemark.postalCode,
                "state": placemark.administrativeArea
            ],
            "dob": dob,
            "email": email,
            "first_name": firstName,
            "last_name": lastName,
            "phone": phone
        ],
        "country": account_number.prefix(2),
        "currency": "EUR",
        "account_number": account_number
    ] as [String : Any]
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, accessing a value in a dictionary will always return an optional. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2885650-subscript

Comment: @JoakimDanielson So for ex. line1 is declared as an empty String, not an optional. When I print the dictionary. line1 comes as an optional string.

Comment: Did you read the link? It doesn't matter what `line1` is declared as, when you do `dictionary["someKey"]` you get an optional value back since there might not be a value for `someKey`. If you want full control of this then you need to create your own custom type to hold the data.

Comment: Another good read if you want to learn more is the chapter in the Swift Programming Language book about [dictionaries](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID113)